# How do i clone my filesystem on the dyno i'm using?

Tags: git, heroku

I'm using Heroku the free hosting solution for facebook apps. When I launch my app everything works fine. But when I clone the app using the following command,

heroku git:clone -a graffiti-galore

I receive all of the files that I put to my server. But I also want the files that were created by my php/flash application. There are a bunch of image files that get written to the file system and wich that heroku git:clone -a graffiti-galore command, it doesn't bring in the new files that are on the filesystem. I know they are on the filesystem but I do not know how to retrieve them.

Please anybody?

Comment: You are cloning only the files that are IN the git system, which means that you either need to add/commit those newly added files to git, or you must copy them by yourself (ftp or smth).

Comment: If they're not in the git repo, how are those files getting there?

Comment: The web app that is running there (php/flash) is generating files. He wants them back on local..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is, intentionally, not possible and is against the principles of the [Twelve-Factor architecture](http://12factor.net) as well as several Heroku constraints like the [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem).

Imagine that you're doing a `git push`, and your server has in the meantime also changed a file you're pushing changes for, leading to a conflict that couldn't be resolved without your manual intervention.

Or imagine what would happen if you scaled from one dyno to 20 dynos. The load balancer randomly sends requests to one of those backends. Some image uploads end up on dyno 1, some on dyno 2, some on dyno 3 and so forth. How do you want that data synchronized across all instances? What happens if you shut one down that has unsynchronized data? What happens on a crash? What happens to 100 GB of stored uploads when you boot 100 other dynos? That's why you cannot and should not store persistent data (such as user uploads) on the local file system; you need to use dedicated external storage instead. There is a dedicated article on uploads to S3 [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-php), and you could also upload straight to S3 from within your Flash app provided you set up the CORS details correctly.

You may also not realize that a `heroku ps:restart`, `heroku ps:scale` and an automatism that runs roughly every 24 hours will, just like a `git push heroku`, lead to your dynos restarting, meaning that all changes in the local file system will be lost.